# Error creating a table in SQLite using CREATE TABLE <name> AS SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, create-table, recursive-query

I am trying to create a dates table that generates EOM dates for a specific date range, but SQLite is throwing an error when creating the table. The current code I have is as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cnt (
        x
) AS (
    SELECT
            0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
            x + 1
    FROM
            cnt
    LIMIT (
            SELECT
                    ROUND(((julianday ('2020-05-01') - julianday ('2016-04-01')) / 30) + 1))
)

CREATE TABLE report_dates AS
SELECT
  date(date(julianday ('2016-04-01'), '+' || x || ' month'), '-1 day') AS month
FROM
  cnt;
```

However, I am getting the error `Query 1 ERROR: near "CREATE": syntax error`. Removing the `CREATE TABLE report_dates AS` line does render the results no problem. What could be driving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cte goes after the `create table`:

```
CREATE TABLE report_dates AS
WITH RECURSIVE cnt (x) AS (
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x + 1
    FROM cnt
    LIMIT (
        SELECT ROUND(((julianday ('2020-05-01') - julianday ('2016-04-01')) / 30) + 1)
    )
)
SELECT date(date(julianday ('2016-04-01'), '+' || x || ' month'), '-1 day') AS month
FROM cnt;
```